# Waffle (or another windows authenticaton method) on Wildfly

Tags: windows, authentication, wildfly, waffle

I am looking to upgrade an aging Tomcat based application to Wildfly. The application currently uses Waffle for integrated windows authentication and I have tried the same approach for Wildfly 29 but it fails with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Unsafe" coming from the Caffeine library which is a dependency of Waffle.

It does work on Wildfly 18 but it seems sensible to upgrade to the latest Wildfly version. I also tried setting up a security domain but the information in https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/master/Docs/wildfly/WildFlySecurityDomain.md doesn't work for Wildfly 29 I guess because Wildfly now uses elytron (whatever that is, I'll avoid the rant about the shifting sands of Java and OSS).

The requirement is that a Windows user using the Edge browser (corporate environment) connects to the server and is automatically authenticated. How do I do this in Wildfly 29?

The application currently works by getting the User Principal from the request and verifying it against a database. Ideally I would like to keep the database based approach but am open to alternative ways of doing this.